# How can I make pinMode calls faster?

Tags: avr, c++

I'm trying to use 3 pins as capacitive pins along side the [Mozzi](http://sensorium.github.io/Mozzi/).

I had several attempts and so far the closest I had was using code from the [ADCTouch library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ADCTouch) straight into the main code, but with the current implementation (removing averaging and taking less samples to speed things up) it's only fast enough to process 1 pin and I'd like to use 3.

Here is my implementation so far:

```
/*  Based on the Gain Example changing the gain of a sinewave,
    using Mozzi sonification library.

    Demonstrates the use of a control variable to influence an
    audio signal.

    Circuit: Audio output on digital pin 9 on a Uno or similar, or
    DAC/A14 on Teensy 3.0/3.1, or 
    check the README or http://sensorium.github.com/Mozzi/

    Mozzi help/discussion/announcements:
    https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mozzi-users

    Tim Barrass 2012, CC by-nc-sa.
*/

#include <MozziGuts.h>
#include <Oscil.h> // oscillator template
#include <tables/sin2048_int8.h> // sine table for oscillator

// use: Oscil <table_size, update_rate> oscilName (wavetable), look in .h file of table #included above
Oscil <SIN2048_NUM_CELLS, AUDIO_RATE> aSin(SIN2048_DATA);

// control variable, use the smallest data size you can for anything used in audio
byte gain = 255;

//ADC Touch setup
int sampleCount[3] = {0};
int values[3] = {0};

void setup(){
  startMozzi(); // start with default control rate of 64
  aSin.setFreq(4200); // set the frequency
}

void updateControl(){
  if(gain > 3){
    gain = gain - 3 ; 
  }else{
    gain = 0;
  }
  //begin ADCTouch 
  pinMode(A4, INPUT_PULLUP);

  ADMUX |=   0b11111;
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC); //start conversion
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADIF); //reset the flag

  pinMode(A4, INPUT);

  values[0] = mozziAnalogRead(A4);
  sampleCount[0]++;
  //end ADCTouch 

  if(sampleCount[0] == 64){//wait for 64 samples
    if(values[0] > 500) {//did we get a touch with all these samples ?
      gain = 255;//amp it up
    }
    sampleCount[0] = 0;//reset count
  }

}


int updateAudio(){
  return (aSin.next()* gain)>>8; // shift back to STANDARD audio range, like /256 but faster
}


void loop(){
  audioHook(); // required here
}
```

The issue is as soon as do the pinMode calls for the second pin I'd like to use (A5) so I'm guessing pinMode needs to work faster. To use `pinMode(INPUT_PULLUP)` and `pinMode(INPUT)` calls for pins A4,A5 and digital 10, now can I write this using direct port manipulation ?

(I'm new to avr/arduino internals and slowly getting the grips with this).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, [figure out which port and pin you're using](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+pin+mapping). Then, manipulate them.

```
DDRC &= ~_BV(PC5);
PORTC |= _BV(PC5);
```

...

```
DDRF &= ~_BV(PF5);
PORTF |= _BV(PF5);
```

...

```
DDRF &= ~_BV(PF0);
PORTF |= _BV(PF0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply(+1). Since I'm still a n00b I had to do a bit of googling. Found [this nice diagram](http://pighixxx.com/atmega328v3_0.pdf) and also found a note that I should rename these constants to ```PORTC5/PORTF5/PORTF0``` and that's how I could compile my modified code. Also, I assume these are for INPUT_PULLUP. and for INPUT I just need to do ```PORT |= 0```,```PORTF |= 0``` right ? Thanks again for your help and sorry to "pull your sleeve", but could use more details as a novice

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza You're not improving your code by renaming the constants. Nobody will be able to understand it when you ask for support or try to Google for information. I'd advise to use the standard names. Download [the full datasheet for the ATmega328 from the Atmel website](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) and read chapter 14. I/O-Ports. The AVR datasheets are usually pretty good and you should consider to check out other chapters too. You'll also notice that these register names are used

Comment: throughout the datasheet.

Comment: @jippie The datasheet actually used `PORTC5` instead of `PC5` in the older versions of the datasheet. My 2009 version does (guess I should update my local pdf file)

Comment: @Gerben Always use the latest release of (any) the datasheet. Check errata if you like, mistakes are corrected every so often an some can cost you lots of troubleshooting time. Whenever possible check the vendor website of a device an use other websites only for backup.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I don't mind sticking to the constants you recommend. Where these be defined so I can include them in my sketch ?

Comment: They're available via `<avr/io.h>`, which is already included by the IDE.

Comment: Hmm, I must be doing something wrong because I added the include but I still get errors finding these constants:```sketch_jan28a.ino:64:3: error: 'DDRF' was not declared in this scope
In file included from /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/io.h:99:0,
                 from sketch_jan28a.ino:16:
sketch_jan28a.ino:64:16: error: 'PF5' was not declared in this scope
sketch_jan28a.ino:65:3: error: 'PORTF' was not declared in this scope
Error compiling.```

Comment: Does your Arduino actually *have* a port F?

Comment: I have no idea, but I'm guessing not since your code doesn't compile ? I did mention I'm new to this and I don't really have control over what I'm doing at the moment. Any hints/tips in the right direction are more than welcome

Comment: ... Let's start with the very basics. What Arduino are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I am using a [SquareWear2.3](http://rayshobby.net/sqrwear/) board which uses an atmega328p mcu

Comment: Take a look at both the Arduino pin mapping for the '168/'328 as well as the datasheet itself.

Comment: Thank you for all the advice. Sorry I haven't marked it. I also found [this library](https://github.com/projectgus/digitalIOPerformance/blob/master/digitalIOPerformance.h#L270) which looks helpful